# Add Users Custom Action on Web Application level on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, custom-actions

I want to add Users Custom Action on web application level which will be found on all Site Collection including newly created Site Collection.

I have tried to add Users Custom Action on Site Collection Level and it will automatically added on each sub-sites.

But How can I add Users Custom Action to Web Application Level so which will be added on each Site Collection and each sub-site of it including newly created Site Collection and sub-sites.

FYI :- I want to add Users Custom Action programmatically using c#.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, if you're deploying [WSP solution packages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231544(v=vs.120).aspx). Then you can just create, deploy and activate a web application scoped feature using the **feature.xml** outlined below. Define your custom actions in the CustomActions.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" 
         Id="{5F377DB6-FDC8-477C-9423-4B16C5FAB505}" 
         Scope="WebApplication"
         Version="1.0.0.0"
         Title="Feature Title" 
         Description="Feature Description">
    <ElementManifests>
        <ElementManifest Location="CustomActions.xml" />
    </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Server side deployments are no longer recommended for new applications. Hence, you should also consider these options for deploying your custom actions:

- Create and deploy a SharePoint App that registers the custom actions. The app can be deployed to a site collection or globally through the App Catalog site.
- Use PowerShell scripting to deploy the custom action(s) to all applicable site collections. Leverage the [Add-PnPCustomAction](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/AddPnPCustomAction.md) cmdlet from [SharePoint Patterns and Practices (PnP)](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP).

The [PnP PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_powershell/pnp-powershell-overview) can run remote, works with SharePoint online and on-premises. I recommend this option the most.

Comment: I don't want to do it with PowerShell. Is It possible through code? Console application or Windows desktop Application.

Comment: Yes, you can indeed write your own code to do it! That's an equally good approach. Using the CSOM, you'll need to add your actions to the Site.UserCustomActions collection. For example with c# as demonstrated in this article: https://andrewwburns.com/2013/12/01/adding-custom-actions-to-sharepoint-using-csom/

Comment: Yes, Exactly i am doing like this only. But I am not able to add it on newly created Site Collection. I can add the custom action on sub-sites if I added the custom action on site collection level. In the Same way I want this to happen for Site Collection.